# How to transfer Proceeds from a gifted property from US to Cuba

Tags: real-estate

Before my uncle passed, he gifted a property via a Deed to myself and a relative residing in Cuba. I want to sell the property, but I have no idea how I will be able to get the proceeds to her in Cuba. Is there a special type of bank I can open for her in the US or elsewhere where the proceeds can be deposited? I have researched banks in the US and it's my understanding that in order for her to open an account in the US she needs to reside here. Any suggestions on how I should proceed to handle her proceeds. Thanks

Comment: This sounds like a scam, but in case it is not - you need to check whether transferring money from the US to Cuba is at all allowed, by either of those countries.

Comment: Where is the property?

Comment: The property is in Florida and no it's not a scam. My uncle deed us a property and now i'm trying to sell it and get her the proceeds in a legal manner.

Comment: Talk to a lawyer. Really. For many other questions in this site, if you get a wrong answer you could lose the money involved. But for this issue, if you get a wrong answer you could get fined or even go to jail.

Comment: It sounds like the property is irrelevant; you just need to know if there is a legal way to send money from the US to Cuba